# SQL Insert Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, derby

I have a table `ARCHIVED_TIMESTAMP` with columns `ID INT`, `ID_ELEMENT REFERENCES ELEMENT(ID)` and `ARCHIVED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP`

I want to create a trigger that automatically inserts in the table `ARCHIVED_TIMESTAMP` after every insert in the `ELEMENT` table the `id` of the inserted element (`ID_ELEMENT=ID`) and the timestamp from the insertion(`ARCHIVED_TIMESTAMP=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)

Comment: What have you managed to do so far?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use CDC for this - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-(cdc)-in-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly then please try something like this:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER TRG_ELEMENT_FOR_INS ON ELEMENT 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO ARCHIVED_TIMESTAMP(ID_ELEMENT, ARCHIVED_TIMESTAMP)
  SELECT INS.ID
  ,      INS.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
  FROM Inserted INS

END -- End trigger TRG_ELEMENT_FOR_INS
```